# Proof that the kernel is a normal subgroup of the domain: repeated line

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

On proofwiki (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Kernel_is_Normal_Subgroup_of_Domain), the lines corresponding to 'definition of identity' and 'definition of kernel' are identical.

Why do we need the second line? Can't we just skip the line 'definition of identity' and skip straight to the end?

Comment: I suppose the is an $e_{G_2}$ missing in the first line.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense. Thanks!